# State not getting updated for Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am using checkboxes to store user preferences and sending it to backend for further processing. I only wanted to store the checked values in my state object. But thats not getting updated. I tried with the Object keys method to determine the checked value. But i am unable to get the value to update my state. I am a newbiew in React, so excuse my for my doubt.
I have provided a snippet below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkedItems: {},
      count: 0,
      formObject: {
        subjects: []
      }
    }
  }
  
  onInputChange = (value, key) => {   
    const { formObject } = this.state;
    const {...formValues} =  formObject;
    formValues[key] = value;
    this.setState((prevState, currState) => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            formObject: formValues
        };
    }, () => console.log(this.state.formObject));
  }
  
  handleChange = (event, formKey) => {
    const {name, checked} = event.target;
    const updatedCheckedItems = {...this.state.checkedItems, [name]: checked };

    this.setState({
        checkedItems: updatedCheckedItems,
        count: Object.values(updatedCheckedItems).filter((value) => value).length
    }, () => {this.onInputChange(Object.keys(updatedCheckedItems), 'subjects')});
  }
  
  render() {
  const checkedValues = {...this.state.checkedItems};
  const checkedCount =  Object.values(checkedValues).filter((value) => value).length;
  const checkboxes = [
      {
          name: "Math and economics",
          key: "mathsandeconomics",
          label: "Math and economics"
      },
      {
          name: "Science",
          key: "Science",
          label: "Science"
      },
      {
          name: "World languages",
          key: "World languages",
          label: "World languages"
      },
      {
          name: "Government and politics",
          key: "Government and politics",
          label: "Government and politics"
      },
      {
          name: "Art and design",
          key: "Art and design",
          label: "Art and design"
      },
      {
          name: "Technology",
          key: "Technology",
          label: "Technology"
      },
      ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
        {
          checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
            <label key={item.key}>
              <input type="checkbox" name={item.name} checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              disabled={!checkedValues[item.name] && checkedCount > 2} />{item.name}
            </label>
          ))}
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I checked your code... Currently you are able to select 3 checked items at max. Right? Now is this the behaviour your want ...? And what are you specifically trying to do. Could you elaborate :)

Comment: Yes thats correct, But whenever i deselect the option from checkbox, the state is not getting updated and the value still exists in the state.

Comment: OK... I got it now. Let me see how to fix this :) By the way How are you? I think we have had the interaction the last time on the same topic.. :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I have a formObject inside my state, where i store values to send the formData to backend. In this checkbox scenario, whenever i uncheck or deselect an option, that value is still present in the formObject and is not removed from there. How to achieve this ?

Comment: We will fix it no problem :) Just give me a moment. Have to offer my prayers :)

Comment: it's Done ..Dear friend :) Have answered it and added the necessary code.. You will be able to send only the checked values to back-End. Do Vote and Accept the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing data to your `onInputChange` function you are always sending all the three values, irrespective of them being checked or unchecked.

You need to only send the checked values. And This is the additional code you need to do that:

```
 () => {
    const arr = Object.entries(updatedCheckedItems);

    const updatedArray = arr.filter((arrkey) => {
      return arrkey[1] === true;
    });

    const result = Object.fromEntries(updatedArray);

    this.onInputChange(Object.keys(result), "subjects");
  }
```

**CODESANDBOX LINK:** https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxissue-zlhtg

**FULL WORKING CODE:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkedItems: {},
      count: 0,
      formObject: {
        subjects: []
      }
    };
  }

  onInputChange = (value, key) => {
    console.log(value);
    const { formObject } = this.state;
    const { ...formValues } = formObject;
    formValues[key] = value;
    this.setState(
      (prevState, currState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          formObject: formValues
        };
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.formObject)
    );
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    const updatedCheckedItems = { ...this.state.checkedItems, [name]: checked };

    this.setState(
      {
        checkedItems: updatedCheckedItems,
        count: Object.values(updatedCheckedItems).filter((value) => value)
          .length
      },
      () => {
        const arr = Object.entries(updatedCheckedItems);

        const updatedArray = arr.filter((arrkey) => {
          return arrkey[1] === true;
        });

        const result = Object.fromEntries(updatedArray);

        this.onInputChange(Object.keys(result), "subjects");
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const checkedValues = { ...this.state.checkedItems };
    const checkedCount = Object.values(checkedValues).filter((value) => value)
      .length;
    const checkboxes = [
      {
        name: "Math and economics",
        key: "mathsandeconomics",
        label: "Math and economics"
      },
      {
        name: "Science",
        key: "Science",
        label: "Science"
      },
      {
        name: "World languages",
        key: "World languages",
        label: "World languages"
      },
      {
        name: "Government and politics",
        key: "Government and politics",
        label: "Government and politics"
      },
      {
        name: "Art and design",
        key: "Art and design",
        label: "Art and design"
      },
      {
        name: "Technology",
        key: "Technology",
        label: "Technology"
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
        {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
          <label key={item.key}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={item.name}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              disabled={!checkedValues[item.name] && checkedCount > 2}
            />
            {item.name}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector("#react"))
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkedItems: {},
      count: 0,
      formObject: {
        subjects: []
      }
    }
  }
  
  onInputChange = (obj, key) => {   
    const { formObject } = this.state;
    let data = Object.keys(obj).map(e =>{ if(obj[e]) return `${e}`;});
    data = data.filter(e => e ? e: '')
    formObject[key] = data;
    this.setState(  {
        
           
            formObject
       
    }, () => console.log(this.state.formObject));
  }
  
  handleChange = (event, formKey) => {
    const {name, checked} = event.target;

    const updatedCheckedItems = {...this.state.checkedItems, [name]: checked };

    this.setState({
        checkedItems: updatedCheckedItems,
        count: Object.values(updatedCheckedItems).filter((value) => value).length
    }, () => {
this.onInputChange(this.state.checkedItems, 'subjects')});
  }
  
  render() {
  const checkedValues = {...this.state.checkedItems};
  const checkedCount =  Object.values(checkedValues).filter((value) => value).length;
  const checkboxes = [
      {
          name: "Math and economics",
          key: "mathsandeconomics",
          label: "Math and economics"
      },
      {
          name: "Science",
          key: "Science",
          label: "Science"
      },
      {
          name: "World languages",
          key: "World languages",
          label: "World languages"
      },
      {
          name: "Government and politics",
          key: "Government and politics",
          label: "Government and politics"
      },
      {
          name: "Art and design",
          key: "Art and design",
          label: "Art and design"
      },
      {
          name: "Technology",
          key: "Technology",
          label: "Technology"
      },
      ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
        {
          checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
            <label key={item.key}>
              <input type="checkbox" name={item.name} checked={this.state.checkedItems[item.name] || false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              disabled={!checkedValues[item.name] && checkedCount > 2} />{item.name}
            </label>
          ))}
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```